# Regex - copy everything up to a certain patern

Tags: regex

yes, I know the title is similar to many question asked before but I have spent a good deal of time on the site before posting my question which is this:

Here is the string:

```
http://youtu.be/-joKveiaabA <br>
```

Here is my regex:

```
 var re = /(?:http?s?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com|youtu\.be)\/(?:watch\?v=)?(.+).*?(?=<br>|$)/g,
```

it works fine with one < br > but doesn't want to work well with multiple < br >'s...for example it won't parse properly such line:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QoQ_dHCi-08 <br><br>
```

code should be something like: ***"copy all characters up to the fist appearance of "< br >" and stop"***

**FINAL SOLUTION:**
I have "improved" Tim's accepted answer a bit. here is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/RfnXu/64/
Now the URL is copied up to an opening bracket so there could be anything after that (*div, br, span, img.*..)

Thanks a lot, once again!! Yahoo!!!

Comment: Looks like a standard regex to get URL should work. `https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)`

Here's a test run https://regex101.com/r/2NDKej/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a greedy quantifier before the lazy one, and both of them are unspecific: `(.+).*?`. Not good. Since a URL can't contain spaces, try this:

```
var re = /(?:http?s?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com|youtu\.be)\/(?:watch\?v=)?([^\s<>]+)\s*(?=<br>|$)/g
```

`([^\s<>]+)` will match one or more non-space characters, unless they are angle brackets. `\s*` will then match any number of whitespace characters before the final check for a trailing `<br>` tag or end-of-string.

Comment: hails Tim! Thanks for your time. indeed this seems to be NEARLY what I am looking for. It does work for the line where there is a space between the URL and the first break line. Though it doesn't if there is NO space. Example:  http://youtu.be/-joKveiaabA<br><br>

Comment: Please check this Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/RfnXu/63/

with space between the url and breaklines it works... with no space-  it doesn't

Comment: Ah yes, I can see why. Just a second.